# InetSocketAddress constructor performs reverse dns

Tags: android, network-programming, android-networking

I've just found out, because of a stack trace reported by a 'hang' in our fing android application:

constructor `InetSocketAddress(InetAddress address, int port)` creates a socket address with an address and the port, but it seems that it also tries to do reverse dns lookup for that provided address, in order to get the hostname.

This is not desired at all, since not only it's not used by our code, but moreover it slows down the application, as our app creates a relevant number of `InetSocketAddress` but always with a yet resolved/translated inet address.

Do you know if there is a way to get rid of this undesired reverse dns lookup?

Comment: Did you try `createUnresolved` with hostname being the IP address as dot-separated string?

Comment: The solution is to avoid using InetAddress.getByAddress(byte[] ipAddress) and instead make use of getByAddress(String hostName, byte[] ipAddress), providing as hostname the string representation of the same IP address.